# Is there a bug in adjRatios TTR version 0.22 ? or I am missing something

Tags: r, time-series

when I trying to adjust the historical prices downloaded from yahoo using getSymbols()
I notice a discrepancy with use.Adjusted=T or use.Adjusted=F.

The different seem too large to be decimal precession.

By running the examples at the adjustOHLC help file,

```
> getSymbols("AAPL", from="1990-01-01", src="yahoo")
[1] "AAPL"
> head(AAPL)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
1990-01-02     35.25     37.50    35.00      37.25     6555600          8.46
1990-01-03     38.00     38.00    37.50      37.50     7444400          8.52
1990-01-04     38.25     38.75    37.25      37.63     7928800          8.55
1990-01-05     37.75     38.25    37.00      37.75     4406400          8.58
1990-01-08     37.50     38.00    37.00      38.00     3643200          8.63
1990-01-09     38.00     38.00    37.00      37.63     3096800          8.55
> head(AAPL.a <- adjustOHLC(AAPL))
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
1990-01-02  32.03023  34.07471 31.80306   33.84755     6555600          8.46
1990-01-03  34.52904  34.52904 34.07471   34.07471     7444400          8.52
1990-01-04  34.75621  35.21054 33.84755   34.19284     7928800          8.55
1990-01-05  34.30188  34.75621 33.62038   34.30188     4406400          8.58
1990-01-08  34.07471  34.52904 33.62038   34.52904     3643200          8.63
1990-01-09  34.52904  34.52904 33.62038   34.19284     3096800          8.55
> head(AAPL.uA <- adjustOHLC(AAPL, use.Adjusted=TRUE))
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
1990-01-02  8.005772  8.516779 7.948993       8.46     6555600          8.46
1990-01-03  8.633600  8.633600 8.520000       8.52     7444400          8.52
1990-01-04  8.690872  8.804478 8.463659       8.55     7928800          8.55
1990-01-05  8.580000  8.693642 8.409536       8.58     4406400          8.58
1990-01-08  8.516447  8.630000 8.402895       8.63     3643200          8.63
1990-01-09  8.634069  8.634069 8.406856       8.55     3096800          8.55
```

The adjusted prices by yahoo adjusted and the adjRatios seem very huge.

```
getSymbols("AAPL", from="1990-01-01", src="yahoo");
div <- getDividends("AAPL", from="1990-01-01", src="yahoo");
spl <- getSplits("AAPL", from="1990-01-01", src="yahoo");
ratio <- adjRatios(spl, div, Cl(AAPL))

> spl
           AAPL.spl
2000-06-21      0.5
2005-02-28      0.5
```

checking at the time apple stock split.

```
> ratio['2000-06-20/2000-06-23']
           Split      Div
2000-06-20     1 0.972553
2000-06-21     1 0.972553
2000-06-22     1 0.972553
2000-06-23     1 0.972553

> ratio['2005-02-25/2005-03-01']
           Split      Div
2005-02-25     1 0.972553
2005-02-28     1 0.972553
2005-03-01     1 0.972553
```

seem like adjRatios() is not returning the correct splitting ratio.

JianHaur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in `getSplits` that was fixed in [revision 601 on R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/getSplits.R?root=quantmod&r1=597&r2=601). The former `as.xts` call wasn't setting the index timezone to "UTC", so the object returned by `getSplits` wouldn't merge correctly with the price and dividend data.

Comment: thank for the answer. setting the timezone to UTC, can avoid the bug for the time being. Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC');

Answer (score 1):

On debugging `adjRatios`, I found out that  there is a code

```
obj <- merge.xts(close, splits, dividends)
if (!isTRUE(is.na(close))) {
    obj <- obj[!is.na(obj[, 1]), ]
}
```

This suggests if for some reason there is no price data on the date when there is "dividend" or "split" data, those splits or dividends will be omitted.

For some reason, there is not price data when splits occurred

```
AAPL[index(spl)]
##      AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
```